# GCM not recieving notification

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate GCM following steps in the google developers site.
I am getting the token but I am not getting any notification from the server.

I have three services

1.MyGcmListenerService.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;


public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);


    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    /**
     * Production applications would usually process the message here.
     * Eg: - Syncing with server.
     *     - Store message in local database.
     *     - Update UI.
     */

    /**
     * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
     * that a message was received.
     */
    sendNotification(message);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.uplogo)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

2. RegistrationIntentService.java

   ```
   import android.app.IntentService;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.SharedPreferences;
   import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
   import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
   import android.util.Log;

   import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
   import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
   import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

   import java.io.IOException;





        public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

        private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
        private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

        public RegistrationIntentService() {
       super(TAG);
        }

       @Override
       protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

       try {
           // [START register_for_gcm]
           // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
           // are local.
           // [START get_token]
           InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
           String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                   GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
           // [END get_token]
           Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

           // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
           sendRegistrationToServer(token);

           // Subscribe to topic channels
           subscribeTopics(token);

           // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
           // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
           // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
           sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
           // [END register_for_gcm]
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
           // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
           // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
           sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
       }
       // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
       Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
   }

   /**
    * Persist registration to third-party servers.
    *
    * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
    * maintained by your application.
    *
    * @param token The new token.
    */
   private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       // Add custom implementation, as needed.

   }

   /**
    * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
    *
    * @param token GCM token
    * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
    */
   // [START subscribe_topics]
   private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
       GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
       for (String topic : TOPICS) {
           pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
       }
   }
   // [END subscribe_topics]

     }
   ```
3. MyInstanceIDListenerService

   ```
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
     import android.util.Log;

     import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
     import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

     public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

   private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

   /**
    * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
    * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
    * InstanceID provider.
    */
   // [START refresh_token]
   @Override
   public void onTokenRefresh() {
       // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
       startService(intent);
   }
   // [END refresh_token]
   }
   ```

And I am doint this in my splash Screen

SplashScreen.java

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                    .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
            if (sentToken) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"token sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"token not sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

And I have given all the permissions in the manifest.

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="app.aguai.medieazy"
android:versionCode="17"
android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<permission
    android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/uplogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.Home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddAddress"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_address"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.UploadPrescription"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_prescription"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.OrderMedicines"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_medicines"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Pharmacies"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pharmacies" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.PharmacyDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pharmacy_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ReviewOrder"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_review_order"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FetchMyOrders"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fetch_my_orders" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyOrders"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_orders" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FetchMyOrderDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fetch_my_order_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.OrderDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddMeasurements"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_measurements"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ViewMeasurements"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_measurements"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.EditProfile2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CircleOfCare"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_circle_of_care"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Adherence"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_adherence"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyMedications"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_medications"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AddMedicine"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_medicine"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ReminderPopUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reminder_pop_up"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".models.RemindService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.models.START_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".models.SnoozeService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.models.START_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SnoozePopUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_snooze_pop_up" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MedicineDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_medicine_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Signup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ReorderDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reorder_details"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2">
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="app.aguai.medieazy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service
        android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.GCM.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.GCM.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="app.aguai.medieazy.GCM.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.
When I tried on other phones, it worked. 
Actually, my phone is Jellybean and in pre-kitkat versions, we need to add this line in manifest

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

When I did, it worked.

Comment: Where did you add this line?